# Accessing sharePoint webservices using java

Tags: android, web-services, sharepoint

```
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><Login xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><username>"myusername"</username><password>"mypassword"</password></Login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
    entity.setContentEncoding("utf-8");

    post1.setEntity(entity);
    System.out.println("calling service");
    String response = client.execute(post, handler);

    System.out.println("response is "+response);
```

I am getting xml response as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <LoginResult>
        <ErrorCode>PasswordNotMatch</ErrorCode>
        <TimeoutSeconds>0</TimeoutSeconds>
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

please anyone tell me where am I geetting wrong?'
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you missing any security requirements? i mean, does your web-service accept password in plain-text or hashed?

Comment: can you please tell how to send it in hashed format??

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following methods to send your password in hash format. But before, check if your server accepts hashed passwords or not, and if it does then which type (SHA/MD5).

**for SHA-256:**

```
/**
 * Perform SHA-256 hash on the given string.
 * It returns a hashed string as Base64 string.
 * @param str String to be hashed in SHA-256
 * @return Base64 string if hashed successfully, else NULL
 */
public static String getHashSHA256(String str){
    String hash = null;

    try{
        MessageDigest digest = null;

        try { digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return hash;
        }

        digest.reset();
        hash = Base64.encodeToString(digest.digest(str.getBytes()),
                  Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
        digest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SHA-256", "Error in getHashSHA256() due to -> " + e.toString());
    }

    return hash;
}
```

**for MD5:**

```
/**
 * Perform MD-5 hash on the given string.
 * It returns a hashed string as Base64 string.
 * @param str String to be hashed in MD5
 * @return Base64 string if hashed successfully, else NULL
 */
public static String getHashMD5(String str){
    String hash = null;

    try{
        MessageDigest digest = null;

        try { digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return hash;
        }

        digest.reset();
        hash = Base64.encodeToString(digest.digest(str.getBytes()),
                  Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
        digest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MD5", "Error in getHashMD5() due to -> " + e.toString());
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: if you have access to server, why dont you simply disable password check and see if your web-call still fails?

Comment: I am using online sharepoint web services, so password is neccessary